# How to avoid loading of a virtual (property) object in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I work in a ASP.NET MVC (C#) project that uses Entity Framework with Visual Studio 2012. I have a class RunSummary that includes a virtual property (object) PatientSummary:

```
public partial class RunSummary
{
    public System.Guid RunId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CenterId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public short RunNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Birthdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Sex { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Race { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Discontinuation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DischargedAlive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AdmitDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeOff { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DischargeDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeathDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CompletedDate { get; set; }
    public string IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> submittedDate { get; set; }
    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isRunLocked { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LockDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isPatientLocked { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DaysDiff { get; set; }
    public short SupportType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Year { get; set; }
    public string customAge { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore] public virtual PatientSummary PatientSummary { get; set; }
}
```

But, I need sometimes to avoid getting PatientSummary when I tried to read RunSummary object. For example, for reports that I make, I need only RunSummary as a source. How to avoid getting PatientSummary? Is there any way in Entity Framework? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Ensure lazyLoading is enabled using `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` Then it will load it only when accessed. Or do you not want it available even when accessed? Note that this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I would like to exclude PatientSummary object when the RunSummary is accessed (sometimes). I don't need the object PatientSummary in reports, that is my reason.

Comment: I think what Ashwin is saying is, if you have lazy loading enabled, PatientSummary would always be available to you, but will not be retrieved from the data store until you try to access it. (There are various reasons this is potentially not good for systems, BTW. But, it is easy.) Otherwise, you're likely specific asking for it (Including it) when you run your query. You would just have to remove the Include.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. But, my query simply is: `List<RunSummary> runSummaries = context.RunSummaries.Where(param => (param.CenterId == centerId || centerId == null)).ToList<RunSummary>();` I didn't use `Include` of PatientSummary in this,but the query works very slowly for centers that have a lot of records.

Comment: I think it accessed PatientSummary when I called `.ToList<RunSummary>()`.